# jquery on change event doen't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Bootstrap [ComboBox plugin](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/)

and I'm rendering combobox inside mvc4 razor view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarFormatId, Model.CarFormats, "Select", new { @id = "SelectCarFormat", @class = "combobox form-control" })
```

and I'm trying using jquery to fetch select change

```
$("#SelectCarFormat").on('change', function () {
     alert('this is changed!');           
});
```

But I'm getting silence, nothing inside user interface, nothing reported as error inside firebug console?

What I'm doing wrong here?

p.s. just to note here that jquery code is wrapped inside `on dom ready`

**Edit:**
Rendered html code is

```
<select id="SelectCarFormat" class="combobox form-control" 
        data-val-required="The SelectCarFormatId field is required." 
        data-val-number="The field SelectCarFormatId must be a number." data-val="true" display: none;>
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="2">Format A</option>
   <option value="3">Format B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you have to use event delegation:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '#SelectCarFormat', function () {
     alert('this is changed!');           
});
```

seems it has been changed with the plugin you are using, so the element you are looking doesn't have any registered event.

---

Because of this plugin it gets changed into this:

```html
<div class="combobox-container">
  <input type="hidden" name="normal" value="">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select a State" class="combobox input-large form-control">
    <ul class="typeahead typeahead-long dropdown-menu" style="top: 34px; left: 0px; display: block;">
      <li data-value="Alabama" class=""><a href="#"><strong></strong>A<strong></strong>l<strong></strong>a<strong></strong>b<strong></strong>a<strong></strong>m<strong></strong>a<strong></strong></a>
      </li>
    </ul> <span class="input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown"> <span class="caret"></span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </span>
  </div>
</div>
<select class="combobox input-large form-control" style="display: none;">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
    <!-- other options -->
</select>
```

[The above one is taken from here.](http://bootstrap-combobox-test.herokuapp.com/)
As you can see the element you are targeting is not there, actually it has been hidden. So you have to change your event binding to this element:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.combobox-container li', function () {
     alert('this is changed!');           
});
```